# Django-Bootstrap5 form validation error not displaying

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap5-modal

I have a form in a modal  that needs to be validate. Since Django doesn't do too well with forms in modals and I not rendering the view after the POST but instead using ajax/js to determine the behaviour. I cannot get the invalid-feedback div to show even though I have followed the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/) which states:

> For invalid fields, ensure that the invalid feedback/error message is associated with
> the relevant form field using aria-describedby (noting that this attribute allows more
> than one id to be referenced, in case the field already points to additional form text).

Additionally, I can view on the console that the "aria-describedby" attribute is set correctly in the input.

#### index.html

```
    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="needs-validation" id="address_form" method="post" novalidate>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="mb-3 row">
                            <label for="id_applicantStreet1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Address Line 1</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                {{form.applicantStreet1}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" id="invalid-street1">This is required</div>
                        </div>
.....
some more other form fields below
```

#### index.js

```
$("#address_submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#address_form").serialize(),
            url: '/ajax/validate_address_modal',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 200){
                    window.location.reload(true);
                } else {
                    responseObj = data.form;
                    for (const key in responseObj){
                        var id_selector = "#id_"+ key;
                        var message = "";
                        for (let i = 0; i < responseObj[key].length; i++){
                            message = responseObj[key][i] + "<br>" + message;
                        }
                        //$(id_selector).next().append(message);
                        $(id_selector).attr("aria-describedby", "invalid-street1");
                        $(id_selector).addClass("is-invalid");
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why does Django not do well with forms in modals? I've done this a couple of times and not seen any issues?

Comment: The view re-renders after the server does the form validation and whatever else it needs to do. When you have a modal which not displayed as the main view but only a popup when a button is clicked, the result is that the modal disappears as soon as the submit button is clicked. I want the modal to stay open if the form submission doesn't pass the validation.

Comment: AH, right, it's keeping the modal open that's the issue. Gotcha.